# Uninitialized boolean value in C++

Tags: c++, initialization, boolean

I'm working on a program where I need a variable with just three states, untouched (uninitialized), true, and false, so obviously a boolean would be the optimal choice for this. But I am having some problems when determining if the bool is untouched. I quickly found out that the bool defaults to 204 or 205, but how exactly can you tell? I've done a few tests on it, and I've noticed that in one of my programs, it was consistently 204, but in another it was 205.

I'm not sure what determines the value, and whether or not it's value varies based on the program OR based on the devise, and operating system being used, but will that value be consistent throughout the program regardless of the operating system or device? As in, would it work do something like

```cpp
    //for some reason the default is only 204 or 205 when in an array
    bool asdf[1];
    const bool UNDEFINED_BOOL = asdf[0];
```

and than using the value of `UNDEFINED_BOOL` through out the program as a comparison to see if a bool (in an array) is undefined? it seems to be working on my device, but would it work on all devices and all operating systems? Is this something that is consistent throughout C++? and is there another way of finding out what the value of the undefined bool will be or is it something that you can't determine without an example?

EDIT: when something is set true or false in the case of my program, there will **NEVER** be a reason to set it back to uninitialized, so that is not something I have to worry about

Comment: An uninitialized non-static and non-thread-local variable is indeterminate, all other uninitialized variables are zero-initialized. Don't read indeterminate variables, you'll just get a belly-full of grief.

Comment: http://thedailywtf.com/articles/What_Is_Truth_0x3f_

Comment: @Deduplicator but if you can determine the consistent value of an uninitialized boolean and you have a list of 2.5 million where you need only three states, wouldn't it be the best choice to use a boolean rather than a larger data structure?

Comment: There is no consistency, the value is indeterminate.

Comment: @Deduplicator Than is there a reason that it's usually 204 or 205 than? or that it has been staying the same for each program of mine?

Comment: Who knows what all happened before, what optimizations are enabled, and all the rest? It depends on all that, and you should not care.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A `bool` holds only 2 states: `true` or `false`. So it would be a terrible choice when you need 3 states (`true`, `false`, `uninitialized`). For this I would recommend an `enum`.

I think you're just misunderstanding exactly what "uninitialized" means. It is not a state of a boolean type. It literally means an uninitialized variable. Using this value is undefined behavior.

---

Edit:

Why are you even considering `bool` when you want to detect more than 2 states? You have simply chosen the wrong datatype. If you want the smallest datatype to represent your 3 values, then choose the smallest type that can support at least 3 values. This would be either `uint8_t`, or maybe you can use a bit field if you're trying to pack this into a structure:

```
enum MyTristate : uint8_t
{
    False = 0,
    True = 1,
    Undefined = 2
};


struct MyStruct
{
    ...
    MyTristate someField : 2;// you only need 2 bits to support MyTristate.
    ...
};
```

Let me also add: You feel that you have found a way to exploit `bool` to detect more than 2 datatypes. There's no reason to try and exploit anything. It also seems you're under the false impression that `bool` is the smallest datatype; it's not. The exact size is implementation-defined, but you won't find any implementation that stores it smaller than a `uint8_t`.

From your comment below,

> ...if I can determine the value of the uninitialized boolean (which seems to always be either 204 or 205)

You can't; it's an illusion. And there is no benefit to knowing these values anyway. They are meaningless. `bool` is either `true`, or `false`, period. If you found some way to determine other values than this, you're working outside the spec and in the land of undefined behavior. The compiler works strictly in the bounds of the C++ spec to allow things like optimizations. The moment you rely on something out of the spec, you're in for a world of hurt.

You change platforms, your code silently breaks.

You change optimization settings, your code silently breaks.

You change some small line of code in a completely different part of the project, your code silently breaks.

There is no way to generalize what the uninitialized value will be. You found that it could be 204 or 205 in your case. How can you know that your compiler won't also generate 206? You can't.

Similarly, how can you know that your compiler's binary representation for `true` isn't 204? Again, you can't.

The bottom line is that you should just use a datatype that is defined explicitly to work in the way you want. **There is *literally no* disadvantage to using a better datatype than `bool`**.

Comment: Using it is not UB. At least not always, under all circumstances. (But language-lawyering those corners is a really bad idea, so never mind.)

Comment: I know that but in my case, if I can determine the value of the uninitialized boolean (which seems to always be either 204 or 205) it would be the best choice, since you could take advantage of the small size of the data structure while also taking advantage of the extra state "uninitialized" gives a boolean. I have a list of 2.5 million so it's important for me to take as much advantage of the smallest data structure as possible

Comment: I recommend using `unsigned char` or `uint8_t`, since a `char` can be unsigned, signed or char depending on the implementation.